# Cant get ruby net/smtp to send html code via email

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to figure out why my html isn't encoded when sending a email using net/smtp ruby. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my class:

```
class CheckAccounts

  def self.emailPwdExpire(email, name, days,  subject)
    begin
      server = 'x.x.x.x'
      from    = "NetworkAccountMgr"
      to      = "someuser@mydomain.com"
      subject = "Network Account Expiration Notice"
      message = <<-MESSAGE_END
      From: #{from}
      To: #{to}
      Subject: #{subject}
      Mime-Version: 1.0
      Content-Type: text/html
      Content-Disposition: inline

      <b>This is my simple HTML message</b><br /><br />
      It goes on to tell of wonderful things you can do in ruby.
      MESSAGE_END

      Net::SMTP.start(server, 25) do |s|
        s.send_message message, from, 'someuser@mydomain.com'
        s.finish
      end
    rescue [Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPSyntaxError]
      puts "BAD"
    end
  end
```

Which gives me this email with no subject and the html is not encoded.

```
 <b>This is my simple HTML message</b><br /><br />
 It goes on to tell of wonderful things you can do in ruby.
```

However when I try to not ignore white spaces using `<<MESSAGE_END` instead of `<<-MESSAGE_END` I get this :

```
ldap_callback.rb:148: can't find string "MESSAGE_END" anywhere before EOF
ldap_callback.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
      message = <<MESSAGE_END
```

Comment: Using `<<-` instead of `<<` allows you to indent the ending identifier. Maybe you are looking for `<<~` which removes indentation from the heredoc's content.

Comment: Using <<~ I get  syntax errors.  @Stefan

Comment: Are you using an older version of Ruby?

Comment: Yes 2.2.3 @Stefan

Comment: Let me update my version, and ill try again.

Comment: That explains the syntax error, `<<~` was introduced in Ruby 2.3. You could strip the trailing whitespace yourself, e.g. `<<-MESSAGE_END.gsub(/^\s+/, '')` (that will remove all trailing whitespace, not just the first level of indentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem, I tested:

```
  message = <<-MESSAGE_END.gsub(/^\s+/,'')
  From: #{from}
  To: #{to}
  Subject: #{subject}
  Mime-Version: 1.0
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Disposition: inline

  <b>This is my simple HTML message</b><br /><br />
  It goes on to tell of wonderful things you can do in ruby.
  MESSAGE_END
```

The issue is with leading empty spaces, we get rid of them with: `MESSAGE_END.gsub(/^\s+/,'')`

---

**EDIT:** That worked well on my email client but as @stefan pointed out it strips empty lines. If you need those empty lines I have three options:

1. `MESSAGE_END.gsub(/^ {6}/,'')` # That works but you would have to update in case indentation changes.
2. `MESSAGE_END.lines.map{|l| l.gsub(/^\s+([^$])/,'\1')}.join` # That works despite of indentation changes, but we kinda sacrifice readability.
3. `MESSAGE_END.gsub(/^[ ]+/,'')` # That was suggested by @stefan and probably reads better.

Comment: _"I tested"_ – really?

Comment: @Stefan, yes for that example is working fine, but `/^\s+/` could be replaced by `/^ {n}/` where n is the number of spaces, but not necessary for this example. didn't it work for you?

Comment: Doesn't it remove the empty line after `Content-Disposition: inline`?

Comment: It does,  but still display nicely on my email client.

Comment: `/^ {6}/` keeps the empty line, but it's weak since OP would have to remember to update the number every time indentation changes, @Stefan

Comment: You could replace `{6}` with something more general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157375/discussion-between-tiago-and-stefan).